# Laravel Impossible to create the root directory

Tags: laravel-5

I am facing this issue in laravel 5.4
I have already given permission to bootstrap and storage folders but no luck.
Does anyone had the same issue. Please share the solution if anyone knows.

Comment: The simple issue in config/filesystem.php  

    
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
             'root' => storage_path('app'),
            //'root' => storage_path('/../../storage'),

        ],

working after i updated updated 

    'root' => storage_path('/../../storage'),

 
to `'root' => storage_path('app'),`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "/" in: /var/www/demo.unigate/storage//../../storag

```
storage//../
```

Adjust ad that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But where should I adjust this? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Post a piece of code you have and I can try to help you. Without that it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file permission like 775 - 777 to write laravel new file in it.

Note : You need to be careful to give permission to file.

Enjoy Your coding!